# Site is built with Bootstrap, Created new landing page with 12-column grid but it's breaking on phones. Why?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

We have a website in WordPress. it's responsive using bootstrap. our agency built the site. I just created a new landing page in the CMS applying the same [row][column] code as on the other pages. The new page looks good in desktop view but not in iPad or phone; the issue is with the images on the page. I've provided a snippet of code below. Note, I've checked and all rows include columns adding up to 12.

Do we need to do something with the CSS to fix this? If so, what exactly? I don't know CSS and am hoping we don't need to rely on our agency every time we create a new landing page in WordPress.

```
[row]
[column lg="2" md="12" sm="12" xs="12" ]

[/column]
[column lg="8" md="12" sm="12" xs="12" ]

<span style="color: #333333;">PLACEHOLDER TEXT</span> [/column] [column lg="2"] [/column] [/row]
[row] [column lg="2"] [/column] [column lg="8" ]
<span style="font-size: 17px;"><strong>PLACEHOLDER TEXT</strong></span>
[/column] [column lg="2"] [/column] [/row]
[row] [column lg="2"] [/column]
[column lg="4" ]<a href="IMAGE URL">
</a><a href="IMAGE URL"><img class="alignnone  wp-image-1011" src="IMAGE URL" alt="Application Portfolio Analysis Benchmark - 1" width="365" height="182" /></a>
<h5><span style="color: #333333;"><a href="IMAGE URL">Click to enlarge &gt;&gt;</a></span></h5>
[/column]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try adding teh class 'img-responsive' to the images, to force the image to ajust to its viewport column size.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind showing me in the code how this is done? I'm still learning. Sorry...

Comment: Edit: I dig some digging on other threads and figured it out. I added the class as follows and phone view is good. Thank you. Other pages on our site don't have this class. Why is it needed on this page and not others?                                                                            [column lg="4" ]<a href="URL">
</a><a href="URL"><img class="img-responsive" src="URL" alt="Application Portfolio Analysis Benchmark - 1" width="365" height="182" /></a>

Comment: I think it has to do with the default image been to wide for the 320 pixels screens causing troubles. img-responsive force the image to be max the width of the column and not the width it is set to if that is bigger than the column width.